# How to connect to local SQL Server?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am trying to run a .NET solution at my local PC, I have set up the SQL Server 2008 and have imported the database.

When I am trying to run the solution and get the connection error:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

The exception is thrown by

```
/// Initializes a new SDEMEntities object using the connection string found in the 'SDEMEntities' section of the application configuration file.
/// </summary>
public SDEMEntities() : base("name=SDEMEntities", "SDEMEntities")
{
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
}
```

I have the specified entity name. The `EntityClient` provider is also specified in the connection string....

The connection string in the `web.config` file and looks like this:

```
<add name="SDEMEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SDEMModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SDEMModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SDEMModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=T2M-03-MECLAB-1\SQLEXPRESS;user id=OEEuser;password=pwdadmin;Initial Catalog=SDEM;persist security info=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Can anyone provide some clue what I should do to solve this problem?

The user id and password are both correct. Is it because of the data source?

Comment: Please show the code which throws this exception.

Comment: Check your `database config` and your `connection string`.

Comment: I've added the entity-framework tag and removed sql-server because your problem is with the former, nothing to do with the latter.